# Rotate a string

Tags: c

I am trying to rotate a string, I think my code is alright but there is something missing.
When i put this: $(echo -ne ‘\tAkjhZ \tzLKIJz , 23y’)”
The output should be: 23y AkjhZ zLKIJz ,$
But it's not working, here is what i've done so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void rotate_words(char *str) {
    char *token = strtok(str, " ");
    char *words[100];
    
    int count = 0;
    while (token != NULL) {
        words[count++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("%s ", words[count-1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
        printf("%s ", words[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        char *str = argv[1];
        rotate_words(str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the last for loop ? The problem is here.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the code not working?  What is the output?

Comment: Please clarify what it exactly means to "rotate a string" - we can guess, but you should describe it clearly. Please show more clearly how you run this program, how the program arguments are provided and what exactly they are, and be more exact about the expected output (why is there a *$*?).

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate from the last element of the array to the first.

```
void rotate_words(char *str) {
    char *token = strtok(str, " ");
    char *words[100];
    
    size_t count = 0;
    while (token != NULL) {
        words[count++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    for (size_t i = count; i; i--) {
        printf("%s ", words[i - 1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char str[] = "aa bbb cccc ddddd eeeee";
    rotate_words(str);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5j7oErEfe

---

EDIT: AFTER @Oka comment:

```
void rotate_words(char *str) {
    char *token = strtok(str, " ");
    char *words[100];
    
    size_t count = 0;
    while (token != NULL) {
        words[count++] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("%s ", words[count - 1]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        printf("%s ", words[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char str[] = "aa bbb cccc ddddd eeeee";
    rotate_words(str);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8YjdfKTs8

Comment: This prints the elements of the array in reverse: `eeeee ddddd cccc bbb aa `. It is not completely obvious, but it seems more like the OP wants to print the final element first, followed by the rest in the same order: `eeeee aa bbb cccc ddddd`, which their code mostly achieves. Seems more likely a problem with their shell, and how the program arguments are captured.

Comment: @Oka you right. His example is not very readable